# Why does `hostname.local` resolution fail

Tags: linux, osx, avahi

I have a number of `Linux` machines, all with `avahi` running and a few `Macs`, all on the same local network.

I often use `ssh` between pairs of machines, using `hostname.local` as the address. Most times this is resolved seamlessly, but sometimes this fails and attempting to `ping` results in the following error `ping: cannot resolve hostname.local: Unknown host`

It is possible to communicate using the IP Address, if I can determine this.

My question is why does `hostname.local` fail, and what can I do about it? It appears to be a problem on the local machine, as rebooting fixes things, but I would rather avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Avahi just handles the server half. You need an mDNS configuration set up for the DNS resolver.

With glibc, it would be in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I'm not sure where it is in other libcs.